# Edited: Relationship between the eigenvalues of $\frac{1}{2}(A + A^t)$ and $(A^tA)^{1/2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transpose

Let $A$ be a square matrix and let $A^t$ be its transpose. I would appreciate references to results regarding the relationship between the eigenvalues of $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)$ and those of $(A^tA)^{1/2}$.

Edit: I edited my question and added an answer to my question.

Comment: If $A$ is diagonal then there is no connection.

Comment: a better question would be to ask about $\frac{1}{2}\big(A+A^T\big)$ and $\big(A^TA\big)^\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References:

1. Remark 2.10 in Eigenvalue Bounds on Convergence to Stationarity for Nonreversible Markov Chains, with an Application to the Exclusion Process by J. A. Fill.    See also the references there.
2. Lemma on p. 288 of CONVEX AND CONCAVE FUNCTIONS OF SINGULAR VALUES OF MATRIX SUMS by R. C. Thompson.
3. Proposition III.5.1 in Matrix Analysis by Bhatia (This one is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value)

Answer (score 2):

Without any condition on $A$, there is no relation. For instance if
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&n\\-n&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $n\in\mathbb N$, then $A+A^t=0$, so its only eigenvalue is zero. Meanwhile,
$$
(A^tA)^{1/2}=\begin{bmatrix} n&0\\0&n\end{bmatrix},
$$
with the single eigenvalue $n$.

Comment: I believe you have a mistake. It should be $n^2$ everywhere and not $-n^2$. The matrix $A^tA$ is positive semidefinite and therefore should not have negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Of course. Thanks.

Comment: I have also edited to answer the revised question. Note that it is considered bad form to change a question after it has been answered. You either force the answered to change their answer, or you make the answer irrelevant.

Comment: I agree about what you say regarding the bad form. I will try to avoid it in the future. Regarding your answer that there is no relation, this seems not true in light of, for example, reference 2 in my answer.